# Jolt transform json to json replace value from constant

Tags: json, jolt

Hello I need transform an json to json, replace key, depending on some
values:

> key: vdevice-name
>
> ```
>  if value of key is 10.127.200.1 replace with "Alfa"
>  if value of key is 10.127.200.2 replace with "beta"
>  if value of key is 10.127.200.3 replace with "omega"
> ```
>
> Input JSON:

```json
 {
   "data": [
     {
       "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
       "dst-ip": "10.161.25.182",
       "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.1",
       "color": "mpls",
       "src-port": 12346,
       "createTimeStamp": 1623334401569,
       "system-ip": "10.157.96.2",
       "dst-port": 12346,
       "site-id": 141011085,
       "transitions": 0,
       "vdevice-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
       "local-color": "mpls",
       "detect-multiplier": "7",
       "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-mpls-ipsec",
       "@rid": 168682,
       "proto": "ipsec",
       "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
       "tx-interval": 1010,
       "state": "up",
       "uptime-date": 1623334260000
     },
     {
       "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
       "dst-ip": "10.162.45.94",
       "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.2",
       "color": "mpls",
       "src-port": 12346,
       "createTimeStamp": 1623334402985,
       "system-ip": "10.157.16.2",
       "dst-port": 12346,
       "site-id": 142011050,
       "transitions": 0,
       "vdevice-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
       "local-color": "mpls",
       "detect-multiplier": "7",
       "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.16.2-mpls-ipsec",
       "@rid": 206290,
       "proto": "ipsec",
       "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
       "tx-interval": 1000,
       "state": "up",
       "uptime-date": 1623334260000
     }
   ]
}
```

> desired Output JSON:

```json
{
   "data": [
     {
       "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
       "dst-ip": "10.161.25.182",
       "vdevice-name": "Alfa",
       "color": "mpls",
       "src-port": 12346,
       "createTimeStamp": 1623334401569,
       "system-ip": "10.157.96.2",
       "dst-port": 12346,
       "site-id": 141011085,
       "transitions": 0,
       "vdevice-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
       "local-color": "mpls",
       "detect-multiplier": "7",
       "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-mpls-ipsec",
       "@rid": 168682,
       "proto": "ipsec",
       "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
       "tx-interval": 1010,
       "state": "up",
       "uptime-date": 1623334260000
     },
     {
       "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
       "dst-ip": "10.162.45.94",
       "vdevice-name": "beta",
       "color": "mpls",
       "src-port": 12346,
       "createTimeStamp": 1623334402985,
       "system-ip": "10.157.16.2",
       "dst-port": 12346,
       "site-id": 142011050,
       "transitions": 0,
       "vdevice-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
       "local-color": "mpls",
       "detect-multiplier": "7",
       "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.16.2-mpls-ipsec",
       "@rid": 206290,
       "proto": "ipsec",
       "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
       "tx-interval": 1000,
       "state": "up",
       "uptime-date": 1623334260000
     }
   ]
}
```

> I'm trying the follow spec:

```json
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "data": {
         "*": {
           "vdevice-name": {
             "10.127.200.1": {
               "#Alfa": "vdevice-name"
             },
             "10.127.200.2": {
               "#beta": "vdevice-name"
             },
             "10.127.200.3": {
               "#omega": "vdevice-name"
             }
           },
           "*": "&"
         }
       }
     }
   }
]
```

> But my output is:

```json
{
  "src-ip" : [ "10.161.25.170", "10.161.25.170" ],
  "dst-ip" : [ "10.161.25.182", "10.162.45.94" ],
  "vdevice-name" : [ "Alfa", "beta" ],
  "color" : [ "mpls", "mpls" ],
  "src-port" : [ 12346, 12346 ],
  "createTimeStamp" : [ 1623334401569, 1623334402985 ],
  "system-ip" : [ "10.157.96.2", "10.157.16.2" ],
  "dst-port" : [ 12346, 12346 ],
  "site-id" : [ 141011085, 142011050 ],
  "transitions" : [ 0, 0 ],
  "vdevice-host-name" : [ "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081", "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081" ],
  "local-color" : [ "mpls", "mpls" ],
  "detect-multiplier" : [ "7", "7" ],
  "vdevice-dataKey" : [ "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-mpls-ipsec","10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.16.2-mpls-ipsec" ],
  "@rid" : [ 168682, 206290 ],
  "proto" : [ "ipsec", "ipsec" ],
  "lastupdated" : [ 1623334401562, 1623334401562 ],
  "tx-interval" : [ 1010, 1000 ],
  "state" : [ "up", "up" ],
  "uptime-date" : [ 1623334260000, 1623334260000 ]
}
```

I need help :)

Comment: I think I can do it with the following:

Answer (score 2):

I did it as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "vdevice-name": {
            "10.127.200.1": {
              "#alfa": "data[&3].vdevice-name"
            },
            "10.127.200.2": {
              "#omega": "data[&3].vdevice-name"
            },
            "*": {
              "$": "data[&3].vdevice-name"
            }
          },
          "*": "data[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your solution works, the subkeys might be converted to substitutions in order to make them dynamic rather than individually repeating them such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "vdevice-name": {
            "10.127.200.1": {
              "#alfa": "&4[&3].&2"
            },
            "10.127.200.2": {
              "#omega": "&4[&3].&2"
            },
            "*": {
              "$": "&4[&3].&2"
            }
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `&4` means going up 4 level and read the key(`data`), and `&2` means going up 2 level and read the key(`vdevice-name`) respectively.

Comment: Thanks Ozhan, the solution that you indicate to me, is to apply in case the key is not "data", right?

Comment: you're welcome @JesusBarrios . No, &4 replaces `data`, &2 replaces `vdevice-name` respectively. Eg. Those mean go 4 or 2 level up and read the key. Best wishes.